# Line up numbers in multiple lines

Tags: python, design-patterns, format, range, line

world!

I'm stuck at a basic question.
We're using simple commands for these questions (format, if, while, and all basics).

I came as far as to be able to produce this:

```
  1  2  3  4
  1  2  3  4
  1  2  3  4
  1  2  3  4
```

by using the following code:

```
number= 0
while number<= 0:
    number = input("Give a number which is bigger than 0 : ")
    if number.isdigit():
        number=int(number)
    else:
        print("Give an integer")
        number= 0
for x in range(number):
    for y in range(1,number+1):
        print(" {}{} ".format('',y), end='' )
    print('')
```

The problem comes with the next question:

```
  1  2  3  4
  5  6  7  8
  9 10 11 12
 13 14 15 16
```

Unfortunately I'm stuck at being able to change the code so it will follow the pattern shown above.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to take a new variable and increment it in every iteration:

```
number= 0
while number<= 0:
    number = input("Give a number which is bigger than 0 : ")
    if number.isdigit():
        number=int(number)
    else:
        print("Give an integer")
        number= 0
z=0
for x in range(number):
    for y in range(1,number+1):
        z += 1
        print(" {}{:<3} ".format('',z), end='' )
    print('')
```

Output:

```
>>> 
Give a number which is bigger than 0 : 4
 1    2    3    4   
 5    6    7    8   
 9    10   11   12  
 13   14   15   16
```

You can also do it in for loop instead of two:

```
for i in range(number*number):
    i+=1
    print(" {}{:<3} ".format('',i), end='' )
    if i%number==0:
        print('')
```

Comment: Oh, how could I not have seen that!
Thank you very much, that's exactly what I needed!